# Update values in the database

Tags: mysql

I want to update the description in table b. In table a I have the newest data. I want to join on all the numbers that are available in table b and update the description. Only the numbers that are available in table b must be updated!

I have this query:

```
select * from b 
left join a.prod_nr = b.prod_nr
```

But how can i do an update to the fields? And how is the performance because there are updated 8000 rows.

I have table a

```
prod_nr description
1       test
2       things
3       pc
```

table b

```
prod_nr description
1       nothing
3       monitor
```

output after query in table b:

```
prod_nr description
1       test
3       pc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update b 
join a on a.prod_nr = b.prod_nr
set b.description = a.description
```

Comment: How can i do this with Codeigniter's active query?